# ¿Cómo entrar a mysql en su modo de consola en MX LINUX?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, linux-xfce

Buen día a todos, he investigado en cómo entrar en modo consola en MySQL pero solamente encuentro documentación para WINDOWS,y no encuentro para Linux.
Estoy usando LAMP (Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP).
¿Alguien podría decirme cómo hacerlo? De antemano, gracias.

Comment: sólo escribe `mysql` o si quieres entrar con una cuenta específica `mysql -u cuenta -p`

Comment: Corre `man mysql` para que puedas ver el manual.

Comment: al escribir mysql me sale este error: Command 'mysql' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de unas semanas de invetigación, logré entrar en modo de consola en MX_LINUX.
El paso es el siguiente.
Como ya tenemos instalado LAMPP en nuestro SO MX_LINUX, ejecutamos el servidor:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Ahora, para entrar a la consola, nos vamos a la siguiente ruta de archivos:

```
cd /opt/lampp/bin
```

Escribmos el siguiente comando:

```
./mysql -u root -p
```

Nos pedirá la contraseña, la escribimos, si en su caso no tienen contraseña, solo presionan [ENTER]
Y ya con eso entramos a modo consola, nos mostrará algo como esto:

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 14
Server version: 10.4.24-MariaDB Source distribution
```

NOTA: Por defecto en Linux, está MariaDB como gestor de bases de datos.
Entonces, mostramos todas las bases de datos que hay, escribimos el siguiente comando:

```
show databases;
```

Nos mostrará todas las bases de datos que hay.

Para seleccionar una base de datos en específico, escribimos el siguiente comando:

```
USE base_de_datos;
```

Y el prompt cambiará al nombre de la base de datos que le hemos indicado, en mi caso me muestra:

```
Database changed
MariaDB[base_de_datos]
```

Espero alguien le sirva. Saludos.